# Cannot add dollar sign variables to Watches when debugging with IntelliJ

Tags: java, actionscript-3, intellij-idea

I have joined a project where function arguments start with a `$`:

```
private function onUpdate($messageObject:Object):void
```

When I try "Add to Watches" with `$messageObject` it shows `"Variable $messageObject unknown"`

But the Variables list shows it correctly: `$messageObject = {Object}[236887609]`.

How can I add this variable to the Watches list?

Comment: What language are you using? Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Action Script 3.0. Why do you need rest of the code? Problem is in Intellij Idea, that cannot show $variable inside Watches tab.

Comment: Can you try something like `($messageObject).toString()` ?

Comment: ($messageObject).toString() doesn't work. But I've found one spike :
add `arguments[0]` in Watches tab - it doesn't shows name, but at least shows value.